# How to add "Active" class when input field is not empty

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create an Angular 4 Directive that will add `class="active"` on the label when the textfield is not empty

```html
<div class="md-form">
    <input appMdbInputInit type="text" name="" id="FirstName" 
         class="form-control"   formControlName="firstName">
    <label  for="FirstName" >First Name</label>
 </div>
```

**Result that I expect when textfield is not empty**

```html
 <div class="md-form">
    <input  appMdbInputInit  type="text" name="" id="FirstName" 
         class="form-control"   formControlName="firstName">
    <label class="Active"  for="FirstName" >First Name</label>
 </div>
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create directive and inject **`FormControlName`** instance to listen to value changes. And add or remove label *active* class when value changes.

**Directive**

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Directive({
    selector: '[setLabelActive]'
})
export class SetLabelActiveDirective implements OnDestroy {

    valueSub: Subscription; 

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private formControlName: FormControlName // Inject FormControlName
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Listen value changes
        this.valueSub = this.formControlName.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

            // Get label
            const inputId = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('id'),
                label = document.querySelector(`label[for="${inputId}"]`);

            // Toggle `active` class
            if (label) {
                label.classList.toggle('active', value);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Unlisten value changes
        this.valueSub.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <div>
        <input setLabelActive type="text" id="FirstName" formControlName="firstName">
        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: this answer helped me recently and i wanted to add, if you have an input and a label after, you can add the class onto the input and style the label with input.active + label

Answer (score 13):

You don't need any custom directive to do that. Example:

```
  <form [formGroup]="group">
    <input appMdbInputInit type="text" name="" id="FirstName" 
       class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
    <label [class.Active]="group.get('firstName').value.length" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
  </form>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/SUmIVCaWnJzjU7j0XHwj?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way would be with a *template reference variable* (see my other answer for a way to do this with a directive):

1. Define a *template reference variable* on the **input** element with **#myInput** property

   ```
   <input type="text" #myInput>
   ```
2. Define a conditional class property binding with **[class.active]="myInput.value"** with the condition being the value of the **#myInput** element:

   ```
   <label [class.active]="myInput.value"  for="FirstName" >First Name</label>
   ```
3. Define a **(keyup)** or **(change)** mock event handler on the  element to trigger Angular change detection.

   - "change" event would activate the class on element blur event, whereas
     (keyup) would enable it on key up. it's your choice which one to
     choose according to your need:

there you go!

---

*complete example code:*

```
 <div class="md-form">
    <input type="text" #myInput (keyup)="true"
         class="form-control"   formControlName="firstName">
    <label [class.active]="myInput.value"  for="FirstName" >First Name</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: This answer helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a simpler, built-in Angular directive **[class.className]** (see my previous answer), but if you insist of accomplishing this with a directive, this is how I would do it :

This is your directive, *makeactive.directive.ts* (don't forget to add it to your app.module.ts file as a declaration):

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[makeActive]'
})
export class ActiveDirective
{
    input;

    @Input() set makeActive(input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        let fn = (this.input && this.input.value) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
        this.renderer[fn](this.el.nativeElement, 'active');
    }

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
}
```

- in your template **app.component.html**, you need to add the directive property to the element that you want to apply the class to (the `<label>` element):

  `<label [makeActive]="myInput">First Name</label>`
- Then you need to declare a **template reference variable** on the text input:

  `<input type="text" #myInput>`
- You also need to register it's "keyup" or "change" event to trigger Angular change detection (either on blur or on key up, as in my previous answer):

  `<input type="text" #myInput (keyup)="true">`

Complete template code:

```html
<div class="md-form">
  <input type="text" #myInput (keyup)="true">
  <label [makeActive]="myInput">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for this one created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yAsehnclANFDP5uupCuE?p=preview).

```
<form [formGroup]="group">
<input appMdbInputInit type="text" name="" id="FirstName" 
   class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
<label [ngClass]="{'active': group.get('firstName').value.length}" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned here you don't really need separate directive for such small thing, but if you want it that way... ok, here it is.

**UPDATE**

Actually, it can be done even simpler. I've updated the code.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppMdbInputInitDirective} from './app-mdb-input-init.directive';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppMdbInputInitDirective
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    activeFlag$: Observable<boolean>;
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.formGroup = fb.group({
            firstName: fb.control('')
        });
        this.activeFlag$ = this.formGroup.get('firstName').valueChanges.map(v => !!v);
    }
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="md-form" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input type="text" name="" id="FirstName" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
    <label for="FirstName" [appMdbInputInit]="activeFlag$ | async" labelClassName="active">First Name</label>
</div>
```

And, finally, most interesting part - **app-mdb-input-init.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMdbInputInit]'
})
export class AppMdbInputInitDirective {

    @Input()
    labelClassName: string;

    @Input()
    set appMdbInputInit(val: boolean) {
        if (val) {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.labelClassName);
        } else {
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.labelClassName);
        }
    }

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

}
```